# HIde Element using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I hide this element? It will auto-populate from an external source. I want to hide this text.

```html
<div style="display: block; z-index: 2147483647; padding: 3px; position: absolute; line-height: 2em; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 11px; visibility: visible; color: red; opacity: 1; background: transparent; text-align: center; width: auto; height: auto; top: 24px; right: 0px;">
  <a href="http://www.cmpany.com" onclick="this.blur();" target="_blank" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">company</a>
</div>
```

```html
<script>
  $('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('z-index') == '2147483647';
  }).css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

I am using this jQuery code to hide the element. It works when I load page 2 times. The first time it will not work then I will reload page and it works.

Is there any option !important function which will apply on this on the first page load?

Comment: If you're getting this behaviour intermittently it's probably because you've not used a document.ready handler and have inadvertently created a race condition between the DOM loading and your JS executing. It works on successive loads because the content has been cached and therefore loads much faster. Wrap your jQuery in a document.ready handler: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

You are using return witch stops the function, no need for that. Also your display none is in wrong place, you need it inside and applied to element like you do for z-index.

```js
  $('div').filter(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index') == '2147483647';
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: block">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('a[href="http://www.cmpany.com"]').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div style="display: block; z-index: 2147483647; padding: 3px; position: absolute; line-height: 2em; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 11px; visibility: visible; color: red; opacity: 1; background: transparent; text-align: center; width: auto; height: auto; top: 24px; right: 0px;">
  <a href="http://www.cmpany.com" onclick="this.blur();" target="_blank" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">company</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $('div').filter(function() {
      $(this).css('z-index', '2147483647')
  }, function () {
     $('div').hide()
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select by using following and hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('div[style="display: block; z-index: 2147483647; padding: 3px; position: absolute; line-height: 2em; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 11px; visibility: visible; color: red; opacity: 1; background: transparent; text-align: center; width: auto; height: auto; top: 24px; right: 0px;"]').hide();

});
```